# Creating MSI installer with WAX toolset always point to 32 bit of Program files

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm creating MSI installer using [WAX toolset](https://github.com/tom-englert/wax), I'm having the following

```
<SetDirectory Id="TFSPlugin" Value="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Plugins" />
<SetDirectory Id="SubscribersFolder" Value="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins" />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="TFSSLAServerSetup">
      <Directory Id="TFSPlugin" Name="TFSPlugin" />
      <Directory Id="SubscribersFolder" Name="SubscribersFolder" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>`
```

Now after installing, WAX ignore the 64bit folder and creates the same folder structure under 32bit version of ProgramFiles!

Any idea what should be done to avoid this ?

Comment: FWIW, Foundational concept:  WiX didn't ignore anything,  the Windows Installer service did.  WiX merely authors MSI database and isn't involved in installing your product. In this case it's trying to "help" you from an application compatibility perspective by observing that your 32bit MSI is incorrectly trying to install to the 64bit Program Files and redirecting to what it thinks you really meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !, In order to tell Wix Toolset that you want to use 64bit of Program Files you have to specify the platform in the package tag

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="200" Platform="x64"  Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
```

note **Platform="x64"**